# Angular: how to connect scope in the controller and scope in services?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have a controller

```
angular
    .module("TestApp")
    .controller('MainCtrl', function ($scope, MyService) {

        var array = [1, 4, 5, 6];

        function remove() {
            MyService.remove('id');
            $scope.array = array;
        }
        render();
}
```

And a service

```
angular.module('TestApp').factory('MyService', function ($rootScope) {
    function remove(id) {
        $rootScope.array.splice(id, 1);
    }
}
```

But I can't find my array which I put into the $scope in controller. I can't see it in the $rootScope. I can I handle this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass $scope as argument to your service method `MyService.remove`

```
angular.module('TestApp').factory('MyService', function ($rootScope) {
    function remove(id, scope) {
        scope.array.splice(id, 1);
    }
}
```

But after that you service is only bag for some function. Please consider to store array in service (in cat be stored in variable) and add methods to read, write, remove elements from yours `MyService`. In that way you are going to create collection pattern.